# Labeling elements using macros in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

Is there is any possibility of adding labels to each MOS transistor element at a given location [`($(M1.G)+(1.3,-0.2)$) node [below] {$M_1$}`] using macros like `\lbl{1}`, so that I don't have to add each time the label with different number like M1, M2...

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1]
        \ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
        \def\Ba{2,0.5} 
        \def\lbl{1.3,-0.2}
        \draw           
            (\Ba) node [nmos] (M1) {} ($(M1.G)+(\lbl)$) node [below] {$M_1$}
            (M1.S) node [ground] {}
            ($(\Ba)+(0,2)$) node [nmos] (M2) {}($(M2.G)+(1.3,-0.2)$) node [below] {$M_2$} 
            (M1.D) --(M2.S)
            (M1.G) node[circ]{}node[left]{$V_B$}
            (M2.G) node[circ]{}node[left]{$V_{in}$} 
            ($(M1.D)+(0,0.25)$)--($(M1.D)+(1,0.25)$)node[circ]{$V_{out}$}
            (M2.D) node [rground,yscale=-1] (vdd){}   ;
    \end{circuitikz}
    \caption{\Common drain amplifier.}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define e.g. the abbreviation

```
\newcommand\mynmos[1]{node [nmos] (M#1) {} ($(M#1.G)+(\lbl)$) node [below] {$M_{#1}$}}
```

and use it as

```
\draw           
  (\Ba) \mynmos{1}
  (M1.S) node [ground] {}
  ($(\Ba)+(0,2)$) \mynmos{2}
```

(see below for the complete code).

You can also introduce a macro just for the label; in this case you can't call it `\lbl` since you already use this name.

```
\newcommand\lblnmos[1]{($(M#1.G)+(\lbl)$) node [below] {$M_{#1}$}}
...
\draw           
    (\Ba) node [nmos] (M1) {} \lblnmos{1}
    (M1.S) node [ground] {}
    ($(\Ba)+(0,2)$) node [nmos] (M2) {} \lblnmos{2}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\mynmos[1]{node [nmos] (M#1) {} ($(M#1.G)+(\lbl)$) node [below] {$M_{#1}$}}
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1]
        \ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
        \def\Ba{2,0.5} 
        \def\lbl{1.3,-0.2}
        \draw           
            (\Ba) \mynmos{1}
            (M1.S) node [ground] {}
            ($(\Ba)+(0,2)$) \mynmos{2}
            (M1.D) --(M2.S)
            (M1.G) node[circ]{}node[left]{$V_B$}
            (M2.G) node[circ]{}node[left]{$V_{in}$} 
            ($(M1.D)+(0,0.25)$)--($(M1.D)+(1,0.25)$)node[circ]{$V_{out}$}
            (M2.D) node [rground,yscale=-1] (vdd){}   ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```